# TextView text formatted based on text value

Tags: android, textview

I have an application where I need to display a list of numbers, but the numbers need to be formatted based on their value.  Negative numbers are shown in normal text, positive numbers shown as **bold**.  Also, the number needs to always appear positive in the text view.  I tried extending TextView with setText overriden as such:

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type) {
    double number = Double.parseDouble(text.toString());

    if (number > 0) {
        this.setTypeface(this.getTypeface(), BOLD);
    } else {
        this.setTypeface(this.getTypeface(), NORMAL);
        number = Math.abs(number);
    }

    super.setText(number + "", type);
}
```

This didn't quite work, as the setText was being called multiple times on the same MyTextView. This resulted in every number appearing bold, as it was positive the next time through.

I would like to keep this logic in a widget, as opposed to where the text is being set, as this is a very common occurrence in my application.

Is there a way that I can do this in a widget?

Comment: Have you tried http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/number-format

Comment: instead of overriding setText(CharSequence) why not make a new setText(double). Also if I recall correctly when I tried getting formatted text I had much better luck with fromHtml() rather than setTypeFace().

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I use the MyTextView in a couple Adapters.  I could roll my own Adapter to use the setText(double), but I think it would be easier to just take care of it all in the MyTextView.

Comment: Ok, I ended up just making an adapter for each list that used this special case, and took care of it in the activity for any other instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ended up just making an adapter for each list that used this special case, and took care of it in the activity for any other instance of it.  Something like this:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.special_text);

    double amount = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_NUMBER));

    if (amount > 0) {
        amountText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    } else {
        amountText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        amount = Math.abs(amount);
    }

    text.setText(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a member variable to your class to check whether it was already modified or to keep the original value.

```
private double originalValue = 0;

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type) {
    if(originalValue==0) {
        originalValue = Double.parseDouble(text.toString());
    }         
    this.setTypeface(this.getTypeface(), originalValue>0 ? BOLD : NORMAL);
    super.setText(Math.abs(originalValue), type);
}
```